# firebase realtime database retrieving data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase realtime database. And I am trying below code. In this code, there is a simple alert("HEY") function supposed to be triggered. But it doesn't trigger.

```
  var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

    submit.addEventListener("click", function(){
        // GETTING CURRENT YEAR FROM LAMBORARI-BASE
        const currentYearRef = firebase.database().ref("lamborari/currentYear/");
        var currentYear = "year";
        currentYearRef.once("value", function(snapshot){
            currentYear += snapshot.val();
            alert(currentYear);
    });
```

And here is my firebase database:
[my firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxysL.png)

Comment: there is no `alert("HEY")` in the code you posted - do you see any errors in your browser developer tools console?

Comment: hmmm `submit` .... I smell a form submit button - which, as you know, results in a new page (even if it's the same URL) being loaded ... look into `preventDefault()` method on an event

Comment: Why "+=" in  currentYear += snapshot.val()